# Overriding split() comma delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am using javascript `split()` method, but I would like to override the comma delimiter with anything else :
e.g :

Rather than having this :

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
//Result : How,are,you,doing,today?
```

I would like to have this :

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
//Result : How%are%you%doing%today?
```

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this ?
Thank you !

Comment: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) return array, not a string. So you can provide to [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method any delimeter that you want

Comment: `str = str.replace(" ","%");`

Comment: Use regex to replace all occurrences `str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '%')`

Comment: @Igor, i try it :-) replace just first space

Comment: `str = str.replace(/ /g,"%");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split is used to split String over delimiter to Array as example:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");    // ["How", "are", "you", "doing", "today?"]
```

and you can split over anything else like split on comma, what you are trying to achieve is to get string and replace space with % can be done by 2 ways:

First: Split over space and get the array each word alone then join them again over the delimiter you want as in this example is comma:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ").join("%");    // "How%are%you%doing%today?"
```

Second: Replace each space in the string with comma, and `/g` g is used to replace all occurrences of the space to not only the first one:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.replace(/ /g,"%");;    // "How%are%you%doing%today?"
```

Comment: typo? `var res = str.split(" ").join(",");    // "How%are%you%doing%today?"`

Comment: but you join by comma, and in comment show `%`? :-) i see you edit this just now :-)

Comment: yee, i thought typo like join => koin but syntax was correct Thanks for notifing me.